# ORA-06550 when trying to check if a table exists

Tags: oracle, exists, ora-06550

I'd like to check weather a table exists before creating one, in an Oracle database.
Though, the following statement is not working throwing error ORA-06550 on line 7 (CREATE).

```
  DECLARE cnt NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('TestTable');

    IF( cnt = 0 )
    THEN
      CREATE TABLE TestTable
      (
        TestFlag NUMBER(1) NOT NULL
      );
    END IF;
  END;
```

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creating tables on the fly in Oracle is a big no-no, so if this is real code you're running then, stop. use temp tables instead.  but the reason for failure is that DDL has to be run in SQL, not PL/SQL.

```
 DECLARE cnt NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('TestTable');

    IF( cnt = 0 )
    THEN
      execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE TestTable (testFlag NUMBER(1) NOT NULL)';
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: p.s you should probably be using USER_TABLES too as if another schema has the same table name, did you want to skip the create in your own schema?

Comment: Thank you for the USER_TABLES hint. I'm using similar code in an update mechanism and don't want to get errors if the query has already been executed (the table has already been created).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do not see any reason why would you want to create a table that way, but here is another approach to create a table if it doesn't exist:

```
 SQL> declare
  2     table_exists exception;
  3     pragma exception_init(table_exists, -955);
  4   begin
  5     execute immediate 'create table TestTable(TestFlag number(1) not null)';
  6     dbms_output.put_line('table created');
  7   exception
  8     when table_exists
  9     then dbms_output.put_line('table exists');
 10   end;
 11  /

table created

SQL> declare
  2    table_exists exception;
  3    pragma exception_init(table_exists, -955);
  4  begin
  5    execute immediate 'create table TestTable(TestFlag number(1) not null)';
  6    dbms_output.put_line('table created');
  7  exception
  8    when table_exists
  9    then dbms_output.put_line('table exists');
 10  end;
 11  /

table exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE cnt NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE lower(table_name) 
                                                            = lower('TestTable');

    IF( cnt = 0 )
    THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TestTable ( TestFlag NUMBER(1) NOT NULL )';
    END IF;
  END;
```